# Possible bug: Close request popup didn't containt content

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Weird scenario. I saw a very unclear question that already had a down vote. I thought I saw the name of the OP before, and clicked his name to look for familiar questions. Then, I pressed 'back' in the browser to return to the post, and pressed the 'Close' link.

The popup that should let you pick a reason now was empty with only the X to close it. After refreshing the page, the question appeared to be closed already. Usually this results in an orange popup telling you that it is closed already.

Comment: Alright, maybe not the most important bug to fix right away. Just figured I should report it.

Comment: That is weird, indeed. Perhaps you loaded the question at the exact moment it was being closed.... Did you get a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, this happens when the question got closed just before you click Close.  The close count you see is often stale.  This worked properly before the update with a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll fetch back down a message about the question now being closed and prompting the user to refresh the page.

It will go live in tomorrow's build.